# Messed up ubuntu 16.04.3 installation,

Tags: boot, 16.04, system-installation, gnu

I originally had Ubuntu 14.04LTS (server) on my laptop, and today I received a message saying that Ubuntu 16.04 is available, so I backed up everything, and commenced with the installation, however some "daemon" packages were stuck during the installation, and the laptop became unresponsive, so I, stupidly, force turned it off. When I turned it back on, I was left with a command-Line interface, with ubuntu 16.04.3 written on the top. I thought, not a problem, and using my desktop, I burned the server onto a flash drive. Now the problem; every time I boot the flash, I am left with something that looks a little like this;

```
GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.12

Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB 
lists possible command completions. Anywhere TAB lists possible 
device or file completions.

grub>_
```

PS; upon booting the laptop, I get nothing. Black screen. With the USB, however, this GNU grub "rescue screen" appears. Upon pressing F12, suring a reboot, selecting the boot from USB option, and typing install, I receive a purple screen, giving a strange looking Ubuntu installation, and upon partitioning space for my hard drive and RAM, it ALWAYS gives an error, I cannot move ahead from this state. An Ubuntu user, more experienced than I am, suggests that the hard drive is broken, which worries me. HELP!

Comment: Good you backed up. 1 Brownie point for that. It's easiest just to wipe the disk and install 16.04.3 from scratch. Use `Erase and Install`... assuming that you're not dual-booting... then you do something different.

Comment: I am not dual booting, how do I `Erase and Install`? All the guides I've checked online are for people dual booting.

Comment: Boot the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, select the `Install` option at the menu. Once the installer starts, it'll ask you what type of installation to perform. There's where you'll find `erase and install`. If you have multiple disks available, be sure to select the correct one.

Comment: Thank you heynnema, but now, after the installation, i am directed to a screen that looks like this; `Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (user) tty1`

Comment: It appears daemon is missing

Comment: Perform a MD5SUM on the .iso you downloaded to make sure that you got a good copy. You may have more problems with the laptop than we knew. Go to memtest86.org and download the free memory test. Burn it to CD or USB and run at least 1 full pass of the test. Later we can check the hard disk. Report back.

Comment: Sorry, again my mistake. Sorry for making you waste your time on this, I just learned that I, stupidly, downloaded the server version of Ubuntu 16.04.3 . I am so sorry. Thank you so much for trying. Trying again with the desktop version.

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to the question title. You can write an answer or delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

The issue wasn't Ubuntu, it was me, I attempted to get Ubuntu 16.04.3 Via the server route, which caused problems for me. Re-trying with the Desktop version. I apologize to all who attempted to answer my questions.